# How do I switch channel in Me TV?

Tags: tv

I've got my USB DVB-T antenna up & running. Also I've got Me TV installed, and I can watch a channel.
My problem is that i don't know how to (supposing here it *is* possible) change channels: I don't see any buttons to do so, and the arrow keys don't work either. Me TV did find several channels, though, so I should be able to watch them.

Comment: The same question on the Ubuntu forums didn't provide an answer: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2032299

Answer (score 2):

At the bottom of the screen there is a small line you can drag up, opening the full tv programs schedule, which allows you also to switch channels

Answer (score 1):

> At the bottom of the screen there is a small line you can drag up, opening the full tv programs schedule, which allows you also to switch channels

if you can't drag up the channels list, press 'v' or select 'view->change view mode', then try again.

thanks @alkemyst